# What is the proper way to return two char arrays as a single string?

Tags: c#, string, properties, path, char

I have a public property in a static class which I want to use as a means of validating the user's input against illegal file and path names.

At present I have this:

```
private static string invalidFileNames = new string(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars());

private static string invalidPathNames = new string(Path.GetInvalidPathChars());

private static string invalidUserInput = (invalidFileNames + invalidPathNames); 

public static string InvalidUserInput
{

    get { return invalidUserInput; }

}
```

Based on Microsoft's documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars.aspx) I am expecting to get back `"<>|"<>|` But all I am getting is the first `"<>|`.

Can anyone shed some light as to what is happening here? How do I ensure that I get both strings returned?

Comment: What have you tried as far as diagnosing the problem? Have you looked at returning the two component strings individually to ensure they contain what you think they should contain?

Comment: Assigning `InvalidUserInput` to a variable seems to return the right value for me.

Comment: @David - If I comment out both char arrays and substitute them with "string a" and "string b" I get string a and string b back as expected (stringastringb), however, if I use private static string invalidPathNames = "string b" all I get back is "<>|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just make it a single string

```
using System.Linq;

public static string InvalidUserInput
{
    get 
    {
        return new string(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()
                  .Concat(Path.GetInvalidPathChars())
                  .Distinct()
                  .ToArray());
    }
}
```

You wont see them all in a TextBox because of the terminator type chars in `InvalidUserInput` in your case its the `\0`(null teminator) that its stopping the display.

if you want to display just the ones that make sense to the user you can strip out the ones that cause the issue using `Char.IsControl`

Here is a static class to wrap it all up

```
public static class StringExtentions
{
    private static string _invalidUserInput = string.Empty;
    private static string _PrinatbleInvalidUserInput = string.Empty;

    public static string InvalidUserInput
    {
        get
        {
            if (_invalidUserInput == string.Empty)
            {
                _invalidUserInput = new string(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()
                      .Concat(Path.GetInvalidPathChars())
                      .Distinct()
                      .ToArray());
            }
            return _invalidUserInput;
        }
    }

    public static string GetPrinatbleInvalidUserInput
    {
        get
        {
            if (_PrinatbleInvalidUserInput == string.Empty)
            {
                _PrinatbleInvalidUserInput = new string(InvalidUserInput.Where(x => !char.IsControl(x)).ToArray());
            }
            return _PrinatbleInvalidUserInput;
        }
    }

    public static bool IsValidUserInput(this string str)
    {
        return !str.Any(c => InvalidUserInput.Contains(c));
    }
}
```

usage:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    string myString = "C:\\InvalidPath<";

    if (!myString.IsValidUserInput())
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("String cannot contain {0}", StringExtentions.GetPrinatbleInvalidUserInput));
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this suggestion, but the .Concat bit is giving me the following error - 'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Concat' and no extension method 'Concat' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Array' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? I have using System; at the top of my source code.

Comment: Thanks, sa_ddam213, using System.Linq has resolved the error. For testing purposes I am outputting the returned string to a text box, but I still only see "<>| there.

Comment: what are you expecting to see? TextBox will never show chars like `\a\b\t\n\v\f\`

Comment: Fair enough, but why would "this string" not be returned along with "<>| if I appended it to private static string invalidFileNames = new string(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()); ???

Comment: Because after "|" is "\0" which terminates the string. see here for more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691087(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your help, sa_ddam213. I like the fact you've used .Distinct() to strip out repeating characters. I'm going to mark yours as the answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can't see them in debugger, but you can output them to the file and see them with some better editor than notepad, like notepad++

```
File.WriteAllText("tmp.txt", invalidUserInput, UTF8Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8"));
```

[image: Screen shot from notepad++]

Answer (score 1):

In this case, because you are presumably going to be using the data numerous times, you would want to only record characters that are unique between both character arrays. To do this, you can use the [Union](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx) method as follows:

```
private static string invalidUserInput = new string(Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().Union(Path.GetInvalidPathChars()).ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

Running your code gives a number of unicode characters returned:

```
"<>|□□□□□□□□□  
□□
□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□:*?\/"<>|□□□□□□□□□  
□□
□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□
```

Are you sure that you are not loosing anything due to the unicode characters?

Also, is that your *exact* code? If you switch the ordering of the variable initalizations it will no longer work as `invalidUserInput` must be evaluated after the other two (they are evaluated in the order they are defined in the code).